# How to add No options Text when there is no place matches my current search in react-google-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, react-google-autocomplete

I am using react-google-autocomplete for searching places. I need to display the No options found text when my current search does not match any cities.In Material UI there is a specified prop for Autocomplete to display the No options found , but I dont know the property for the react-google-autocomplete
I need the solution for my above issue.

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve the outcome? Provide the code that is related to your question etc.

Comment: Please provide the code